# Passing State Upwards in Functional Components Without Context

Tags: reactjs

Hi so if the easiest answer is go implement context, i'd have to refactor everything back to context, but it was probably gonna happen anyway.

but.... I am building a blog component on a sales site that pushes a modal to the screen and makes the image that makes the link disappear. Then on the Modal is an X. in order to launch the modal I am resolving a boolean of visible that is triggered as part of an onClick event. Id like to then trigger a state change on the value visible and send it up from the Modal back to the img that launches the modal.

How can i pass boolean up in stateless functional components?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import BlogModal from "./BlogModal";

const BlogItem = ({ blog: { id, img, title, teaser, body, postDate } }) => {
 const blog = { id, img, title, teaser, body, postDate };
 const [pointer, setPointer] = useState(false);
 const [itemStyle, setItemStyle] = useState({});
 const [visible, setVisible] = useState(true);

 const onMouseEnter = e => {
  setPointer(true);
 };

 const onMouseLeave = e => {
  setPointer(false);
 };

 const onClick = e => {
  setVisible(false);
  setItemStyle({
   visibility: "hidden"
  });
 };

 return (
  <div onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter} onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}>
   {pointer && visible ? (
    <div className='employeegrid' style={{ height: "200px", width: "200px" }}>
     <div
      className='image'
      style={{
       height: "200px",
       width: "200px",
       top: 0,
       left: 0,
       zIndex: "1"
      }}>
      <img
       style={{
        height: "200px",
        width: "200px",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        zIndex: "1"
       }}
       src={img}
       alt=''
      />
     </div>
     <div
      className='text'
      style={{
       height: "200px",
       width: "200px",
       top: 0,
       left: 0,
       opacity: "66%",
       zIndex: "1"
      }}>
      <ul
       className='all-center'
       style={{
        height: "200px",
        width: "200px",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        zIndex: "1"
       }}
       className='bg-dark'>
       <li className='text-center'>
        <strong>{title}</strong>
       </li>
       <li>{postDate}</li>
       <li className='text-center'>{teaser}</li>

       <li>
        <a className='btn btm-sm btn-primary' onClick={onClick}>
         Read more...
        </a>
       </li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   ) : (
    <div>
     {visible ? (
      <img style={{ height: "200px", width: "200px" }} src={img} alt='' />
     ) : (
      ""
     )}
    </div>
   )}
   {!visible ? <BlogModal key={blog.id} blog={blog} visible={visible} /> : ""}
  </div>
 );
};

export default BlogItem;
```

the !visible is what needs to change obviously and it needs to be pushed up from the button on modal

```
import React, { useState, Link } from "react";

const BlogModal = ({
 blog: { id, img, title, teaser, body, postDate },
 setVisible
}) => {
 return (
  <div className='bg-light'>
   <nav className='navbar'>
    <button onClick={() => setVisible(true)}>x</button>
    <h3 className='lead text-primary text-center'>{title}</h3>
   </nav>
  </div>
 );
};

export default BlogModal;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, you can pass down and use a callback function instead of passing around a boolean.

When using state that toggles a `boolean`, I recommend using the callback function to synchronously update it: `setState(prevState => !prevState)`. This basically means take the previous state: `false`/`true` and return its reciprocated value.

As a side note: When making components, try to make them reusable. For example, you can utilize a single component to display the blog content by passing in a `boolean` value to either show a `read more` button or the blog's `body`. In addition, if you want to destructure an object from within another component, then you can use the spread syntax: `<Example {...blog} />`. Now in `Example`, we can destructure `blog` props directly: `const Example = ({ id, body, title, postDate )} => { ... };`

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Blog Modal Example]

**Demo**: https://o13bo.csb.app/

---

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import BlogItem from "./components/BlogItem";
import "./styles.css";

const blog = {
  id: "123456789",
  title: "Camping Trip",
  body:
    "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
  teaser: "We tried to camp and this happened",
  postDate: "March 19th, 2020 @ 1:30PM",
  img: "https://i.imgur.com/raX9K2D.png"
};

const App = () => (
  <div className="app">
    <h1>Blog</h1>
    <BlogItem blog={blog} />
  </div>
);

export default App;
```

**components/BlogItem/index.js**

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import Modal from "../Modal";
import BlogContent from "../BlogContent";

const BlogItem = ({ blog }) => {
  const [isPreviewing, setPreviewState] = useState(false);
  const [showModal, setModalState] = useState(false);

  const toggleVisibility = useCallback(() => {
    setModalState(prevState => !prevState);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseEnter = useCallback(() => {
    setPreviewState(true);
  }, []);

  const handleMouseLeave = useCallback(() => {
    setPreviewState(false);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div
      className="uk-card uk-card-default uk-card-body uk-card-hover"
      onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      <div className="blog-details">
        <img src={blog.img} alt="" />
        {isPreviewing && !showModal ? (
          <BlogContent
            {...blog}
            showReadMore
            toggleVisibility={toggleVisibility}
          />
        ) : null}
        {showModal && <Modal {...blog} toggleVisibility={toggleVisibility} />}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BlogItem;
```

**components/BlogContent/index.js**

```
import React from "react";

const BlogContent = ({
  body,
  img,
  title,
  postDate,
  teaser,
  toggleVisibility,
  showReadMore
}) => (
  <div className="blog-details">
    {!showReadMore && (
      <div className="blog-image-container">
        <img src={img} alt="" />
      </div>
    )}
    <h3 className="uk-card-title">{title}</h3>
    <div className="post-date">{postDate}</div>
    <div>
      {teaser}&hellip;&nbsp;{!showReadMore && body}
    </div>
    {showReadMore && (
      <div className="button-container">
        <button
          type="button"
          className="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-button-small"
          onClick={toggleVisibility}
        >
          Read more
        </button>
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);

export default BlogContent;
```

**components/Modal/index.js**

```
import React from "react";
import BlogContent from "../BlogContent";
import CloseButton from "../CloseButton";

const Modal = props => (
  <>
    <div className="bg-overlay" />
    <div className="window-container">
      <div className="modal-container">
        <div className="center-modal">
          <div className="modal-content">
            <CloseButton onClick={props.toggleVisibility} />
            <BlogContent {...props} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </>
);

export default Modal;
```